# Duplicate symbol error with ReachabilityRef on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, duplicates, sharekit

I am using ShareKit and BCFads sdk in my iPhone app.
When I build the app, I've got an duplicate symbol error.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in /BCFAds/BCFAds.a(Reachability.o) and /Debug-iphonesimulator/libShareKit.a(Reachability.o) for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

This problem comes from ReachabilityRef.
It is defined in the Reachability.m of the sharekit.

```
@interface Reachability: NSObject
{
 BOOL localWiFiRef;
 SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your project if you have 2 Reachability.{h/m} hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks. but I cannot find reachability from the BCFAds.